# MongoDB support on RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, rubymine

I am using RubyMine for Rails Development i want to use MongoDB for the database. I have installed MongoDB on my Ubuntu System. and installed the IDE's Plugin for Mongo as well. Still i am not able to set up a project with mongoDB support.

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/dboissier/mongo4idea

Comment: @ahmet i have already added that to the libs. but when i create a new project i cant choose mongodb as the database

Comment: @ahmet have added a screenshot

Comment: You know you can do screen capture, right? In any case, the image doesn't help at all.

Comment: @DaveNewton i am not able to do it with the dropdown activated :P

Comment: I don't think it comes with a preconfiguration setup, just change your database.yml to point to the mongodb server setup inside jetbrains after you have selected one of those options from the dropdown

Comment: [link](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/whatsnew/) 
On the column 4.5 says: Mongoid/MongoDB integration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Notes](http://mrpmorris.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/installing-ruby-on-rails-rubymine-and.html) on a clean install to Ubuntu with RoR and MongoDB. Has you do all the configuration yourself though, no use of the plugin. This is a last resort.

Another useful doc [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/). It is the MongoDB doc on installing on Ubuntu.

Did you restart RubyMine after installing the plugin? Log out / Restart from your current session on desktop?

When you installed MongoDB, did you use the default repo that came with Ubuntu or did you use the link mentioned above to install?

-Is the Mongo server actually running?

--Go to terminal and try `sudo service mongodb restart`

---Try accessing the URI for administration. See [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/)